# Trouble creating checkbox array with 2 items being checked by default in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, checkbox, checked

Im working with a Wordpress theme.
The code I am having trouble with is relevant to a filter divided into "action" and "categories".

I would like to have 2 checkboxes checked by default (1 action & 1 category) and the rest blank.

I'm at a complete loss, any help would be sincerely appreciated.
here is the code:

```
    <?php
    $icons          =   array();
    $taxonomy       =   'property_action_category';
    $tax_terms      =   get_terms($taxonomy);
    $taxonomy_cat   =   'property_category'; 
    $categories     =   get_terms($taxonomy_cat);

    // add only actions
    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
    $icon_name              =   'wp_estate_icon'.$tax_term->slug;
    $icons[$tax_term->slug] =   esc_html( get_option($icon_name) );  
    }

    // add only categories
    foreach ($categories as $categ) {
    $icon_name              =   'wp_estate_icon'.$categ->slug;
    $icons[$categ->slug]    =   esc_html( get_option($icon_name) );  
    }
    ?>

    <div class="gmap_wrapper  <?php
    if (!is_front_page()) {
        print 'gmap_not_home" style="height:295px;"';
    }else{
        print'"';
    }
    ?>>
    <div class="gmap-next <?php if (is_front_page()) print 'is-front'; ?>" id="gmap-next" >       </div>
    <div class="gmap-prev <?php if (is_front_page()) print 'is-front'; ?>" id="gmap-prev" >    </div>

    <?php 
    $geo_status     =   esc_html ( get_option('wp_estate_geolocation','') );
    $custom_image   =   esc_html( esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page_custom_image',    true)) );  
    $rev_slider     =   esc_html( esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rev_slider', true)) );

    if($geo_status=='yes' && $custom_image=='' && $rev_slider==''){ 
      print'  <div id="mobile-geolocation-button"></div>';
    } 
    ?>

    <div id="googleMap" <?php
         $home_small_map_status= esc_html ( get_option('wp_estate_home_small_map','') );
        if (!is_front_page() || ( is_front_page() && $home_small_map_status=='yes' ) ) {
            print 'style="height:295px;"';
        }
        ?>    
    </div>    


   <div class="tooltip"> <?php _e('click to enable zoom','wpestate');?></div>
   <div id="gmap-loading"><?php _e('Loading Maps','wpestate');?>
       <span class="gmap-animation">
            <img src="<?php print get_template_directory_uri(); 
    ?>
       </span>
   </div>


   <?php
   ////////////////////////// enable /disable map filters
   $show_filter_map_status  =  esc_html ( get_option('wp_estate_show_filter_map','') );
   $home_small_map_status   =  esc_html ( get_option('wp_estate_home_small_map','') );
   if($show_filter_map_status!='no'){
   ?>

   <div class="gmap-menu-wrapper" >   
        <div class="gmap-menu" id="gmap-menu" <?php if (!is_front_page() ||   (is_front_page() && $home_small_map_status=='yes') ) print 'style="display:none;"'; ?> >
            <div id="closefilters"></div>
            <div class="action_filter" >
                <?php

                foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
                        print '<div class="checker"><input type="checkbox"   checked="checked"  name="filter_action[]" id="'.$tax_term->slug.'" class="'.$tax_term- >slug.'"  value="'.$tax_term->name.'"/><label for="'.$tax_term->slug.'"><span></span>';
                        if( $icons[$tax_term->slug]!='' ){
                             print '<img src="'.$icons[$tax_term->slug].'"  alt="'.$tax_term->name.'">' . $tax_term->name . '</label></div>';
                        }else{
                             print '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/css/css-  images/'.$tax_term->slug.'icon.png" alt="'.$tax_term->name.'">' . $tax_term->name .  '</label></div>';
                        }
                }
                ?>
            </div>

            <div class="type-filters">
                <?php
                foreach ($categories as $categ) {
                     print '<div class="checker"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"   name="filter_type[]" id="'.$categ->slug.'"  class="' . $categ->slug . '" value="' . $categ->name . '"/><label for="' . $categ->slug. '"><span></span>';
                     if( $icons[$categ->slug]!='' ){
                         print' <img src="'.$icons[$categ->slug].'" alt="'.$categ->slug.'">' . $categ->name . '</label></div>';
                     }else{
                         print' <img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/css/css-images/'.$categ->slug.'icon.png" alt="'.$categ->name.'">' . $categ->name . '</label></div>';
                     }                      
                }
                ?>  
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </div> `enter code here`
```

Thanks
Kyle

Comment: What is it doing now? All checkboxes are checked?

Comment: Ohhh so much of code, just use `in_array()` and it will help you

Comment: Right now you are marking all checkboxes as `checked="checked"` to just check the first one you could add an index to your foreach loop and do something like `'.($index == 0 ? ' checked="checked"' : '').'`

Comment: Hello,

@ Putvande - That is correct, all checkboxes are currently checked by default.

Comment: @ Mr. Alien, thank you, I'm just not sure where in the code i would insert this, i'd assume id need to edit that foreach loop?

@ Krister, i've tried adding that line of code within the foreach loop but I keep getting syntax errors.

I have values assigned to each Action, i.e Sales, Rent, Foreclosure, Other.

Please could you give me an example within the foreach loop below that I could insert this and check only "Sales" and "Rentals"?

I'll paste the foreach code below for ease of reference.

Comment: <?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
print '<div class="checker"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"  name="filter_action[]" id="'.$tax_term->slug.'" class="'.$tax_term->slug.'"  value="'.$tax_term->name.'"/><label for="'.$tax_term->slug.'"><span></span>';
if( $icons[$tax_term->slug]!='' ){
print '<img src="'.$icons[$tax_term->slug].'" alt="'.$tax_term->name.'">' . $tax_term->name . '</label></div>';}else{ print '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/css/css-images/'.$tax_term->slug.'icon.png" alt="'.$tax_term->name.'">' . $tax_term->name . '</label></div>';}}?>